# R replace variable values

Tags: r, variables, replace

I try to change variable values in WVS dataset from carData package, but I have an error:

```r
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, religion, value = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  : 
  replacement has 5383 rows, data has 5381
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, c("yes", "no"), value = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Religion is factor variable and it should still remain factor.

That's my code

```r
data(WVS) 
head(WVS)
WVS$religion[c("yes","no")] <- c("oui", "non")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
WVS  <- WVS %>% mutate(religion = if_else("yes","oui","non"))
```

If you variable can have more options you don't want to mess, you can use `case_when`:

```r
WVS  <- WVS %>%
   mutate(religion = case_when(religion == "yes" ~ "oui",
                               religion == "no" ~ "non",
                               TRUE ~ religion))
```

## Edit

You can use [recode](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html) with factor variables

```r
WVS  <- WVS %>%
   mutate(religion = recode(religion, 
                            yes = "oui",
                            no = "non"))
```

Comment: Does `WVS$religion` for sure only have "yes" and "no" values? Cause otherwise you're overwriting some of them. Safer to do nested if else, no?

Comment: I guessed it did from the example. Otherwise, yes it's safer to do differently, I proposed a `case_when` solution but nested if else could do the job

Comment: What if religion is factor variable and I want that will be still factor? case_when doesn't work.

Comment: With factor variables, use `recode`. If you are happy with the solution, you can accept it [see guidelines there if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)